# Redirect based on URL parameter and if URL parameter is available in table row - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, mysqli, url-parameters

I have a table where one of the attribute is version.

The table name is versions.

I want to redirect users to a default page if the URL parameter also called version is NULL or not present, and if the version value is not in my table.

So far I've this. It does not work.

```
$stonevar = isset($_GET['version']) ? $_GET['version'] : NULL;

if (empty($stonevar)) {
header("Location: index.php?version=default");
 }

$id = $_GET['version'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `versions` WHERE version='$id'");

 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $varex = $row['version'];
 }

if ($varex == NULL) {
header("Location: index.php?default");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add exit(); after header function.

Try Something like:

```
  <?php
    $stonevar = isset($_GET['version']) ? $_GET['version'] : NULL;

    if (empty($stonevar)) {
    header("Location: index.php?version=default");
    exit();
     }

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `versions` WHERE version='$stonevar'");

     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    header("Location: index.php?".$row['version']);
    exit();
/*
* or something you want to do if version exist
*/
     }

    header("Location: index.php?default");
    exit();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$result->num_rows` to count the result and see if the version exists.

```
$stonevar = isset($_GET['version']) ? $_GET['version'] : NULL;

if (empty($stonevar)) {
header("Location: index.php?version=default");
 }

$id = $_GET['version'];
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `versions` WHERE version='$id'");

$total_num_rows = $result->num_rows;

if ($total_num_rows>0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $varex = $row['version'];
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php?default");
}
```